# Why selection range in textarea resets to 0?

Tags: javascript

I have some IMG emojis which can be inserted in textarea as their string representations. A script below must get caret position and insert the representation at the right place but sometimes it misfires and reset the selection range in 0.

You can see it playing around with example clicking on smiles and inside textarea. I have reset to 0 right after setting the caret at end of textarea content.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var doc = window.document;
var smiles = doc.getElementById('chat-smiles-panel').getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        var el    = doc.getElementById('chat-textarea');
        for (var i = 0; i < smiles.length; i++) {
            smiles[i].onclick = function(e) {
                var elem, evt = e?e:event;
                elem = (evt.target)?evt.target:evt.srcElement;
                var newText = elem.getAttribute('data-smile');
                console.log('before', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
                var start = el.selectionStart;
                var end   = el.selectionEnd;
                var text  = el.value;
                var before = text.substring(0, start);
                var after  = text.substring(end, text.length);
                el.value = (before + newText + after);
                start = end = start + newText.length;
                el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
                console.log('after', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
            }
        }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="chat-smiles-panel">
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/slightly-smiling-face_1f642.png" alt="smiley" data-smile=":smiley:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/rolling-on-the-floor-laughing_1f923.png" alt="lol" data-smile=":lol:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/smiling-face-with-halo_1f607.png" alt="angel" data-smile=":angel:" />
  </div>
  <textarea id="chat-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Caret positions before and after emoji insertion seeng everytime in console log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I think you know, `el.value = (before + newText + after);` wipes out the value and replaces it with a new value, moving the cursor back to the beginning of the field.

I think for the `setSelectionRange` after that to work cross-browser, the field has to have focus again. That seems to be the case in Chrome anyway, since this (with `el.focus()`) works:

```js
window.onload = function() {
var doc = window.document;
var smiles = doc.getElementById('chat-smiles-panel').getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        var el    = doc.getElementById('chat-textarea');
        for (var i = 0; i < smiles.length; i++) {
            smiles[i].onclick = function(e) {
                var elem, evt = e?e:event;
                elem = (evt.target)?evt.target:evt.srcElement;
                var newText = elem.getAttribute('data-smile');
                console.log('before', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
                var start = el.selectionStart;
                var end   = el.selectionEnd;
                var text  = el.value;
                var before = text.substring(0, start);
                var after  = text.substring(end, text.length);
                el.value = (before + newText + after);
                el.focus();  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Added
                start = end = start + newText.length;
                el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
                console.log('after', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
            }
        }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="chat-smiles-panel">
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/slightly-smiling-face_1f642.png" alt="smiley" data-smile=":smiley:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/rolling-on-the-floor-laughing_1f923.png" alt="lol" data-smile=":lol:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/smiling-face-with-halo_1f607.png" alt="angel" data-smile=":angel:" />
  </div>
  <textarea id="chat-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

In a comment you've asked:

> And no solutions if I don't want set the focus on the textarea? I asked cause I try to make UI more friendly hidding the emoji pannel when the textarea gets focus. So when the script sets focus after inserting emoji the emojis pannel slides away and it's not good.

To handle that, I *tried* to grab the active element before using `focus`:

```
// Didn't work
var active = document.activeElement;
el.focus();
el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
if (active) {
    active.focus();
}
```

When that didn't work, I punted and used `el.blur()`, which works (though I don't like it much):

```js
window.onload = function() {
var doc = window.document;
var smiles = doc.getElementById('chat-smiles-panel').getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        var el    = doc.getElementById('chat-textarea');
        for (var i = 0; i < smiles.length; i++) {
            smiles[i].onclick = function(e) {
                var elem, evt = e?e:event;
                elem = (evt.target)?evt.target:evt.srcElement;
                var newText = elem.getAttribute('data-smile');
                console.log('before', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
                var start = el.selectionStart;
                var end   = el.selectionEnd;
                var text  = el.value;
                var before = text.substring(0, start);
                var after  = text.substring(end, text.length);
                el.value = (before + newText + after);
                el.focus();  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Added
                start = end = start + newText.length;
                el.setSelectionRange(start, end);
                el.blur();   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Added
                console.log('after', el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
            }
        }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="chat-smiles-panel">
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/slightly-smiling-face_1f642.png" alt="smiley" data-smile=":smiley:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/rolling-on-the-floor-laughing_1f923.png" alt="lol" data-smile=":lol:" />
    <img width="20" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/apple/155/smiling-face-with-halo_1f607.png" alt="angel" data-smile=":angel:" />
  </div>
  <textarea id="chat-textarea">Testing 1 2 3</textarea>
</div>
```

I'd lean toward making the emojis panel a bit smarter about disappearing, such as adding a one-second delay from the last time it was used, so that if you want to add multiple emojis, you can, but then it disappears a second after the last one.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I haven't been able to get the snippet to do anything weird. (Firefox)

Comment: @Pointy - I wasn't right, but I think I am now. :-) I hit send too soon. You can see the problem on Chrome, doesn't happen (for me) on Firefox. With the OP's snippet: If you type some text into the field, position the cursor somewhere within it, and then click an emoji, it inserts it in the right place but doesn't focus the field. If you tab to focus the field again, the cursor is at the start of the field. (In Firefox it's where it was when you clicked the emoji.) With my change above, clicking an emoji inserts it and leaves you in the field, in the correct place, in both browsers.

Comment: And no solutions if I don't want set the focus on the textarea? I asked cause I try to make UI more friendly hidding the emoji pannel when the textarea gets focus. So when the script sets focus after inserting emoji the emojis pannel slides away and it's not good

Comment: @Mik - I've updated the answer to address that comment.

Comment: I guess we can assume the problem is solved. If we can't do without focus I'll found another way to improve usability.

Comment: @Mik - If you *do* find a way to do it without focus, would you come back and post an answer, switch the checkmark to it, and ping me to let me know? Because that would be cool. :-) You could also file an issue with the Chromium project, since it seems like it should be possible to set the selection w/o focus. Finally: I noticed just now that even with your original code, Edge doesn't move focus away from the textarea when you click an emoji, so you'll want to allow for that with your testing. (Edge will switch to using Blink which should make it behave like Chrome, but that's in the future.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , unfortunately I didn't find another way, I just changed UI and removed the panel hidding by the textarea focusing. Thank you for clarifications to the solution!

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for the problem for about 4 hours.